# I want to search and list google spreadsheet that start with "A3_" in my google drive & log file id, url and owner name into another google sheet

Tags: google-apps-script

I have this code, but this gives an error of cannot read property 'getName' of null
how do I fix this. There are about 2000 files on my drive. There are files shared by other users as well.

```
 function getMyFilesFromDrive() {
 var myFiles = DriveApp.searchFiles('title contains "A3_"');
 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Files");

 sheet.clear();
 var rows = [];
 rows.push(["ID", "Name", "Url", "user"]);
 while(myFiles.hasNext()) {
   var file = myFiles.next();
   if(file != null) {
     rows.push([file.getId(), file.getName(), file.getUrl(), file.getOwner().getName()]);
   }
 }
 sheet.getRange(1,1,rows.length,4).setValues(rows);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Find Spreadsheets

This is what I use:

```
function getSpreadsheets() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Files');
  if (sh.getLastRow() > 1) {
    const rg = sh.getRange(2, 1, sh.getLastRow() - 1, sh.getLastColumn());
    rg.clearContent();
    SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  }
  var token = '';
  var vA = [["Id", "MimeType", "Kind", "Title", "Path", "OwnerEmails"]];
  do {
    let resp = Drive.Files.list({ pageToken: token, q: "mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet'" });
    token = resp.nextPageToken;
    for (let i = 0; i < resp.items.length; i++) {
      let item = resp.items[i];
      if (item.title.match(/^A3_.*$/)) {//with names that begin with A3_
        vA.push([item.id, item.mimeType, item.kind, item.title, getPathFromId(item.id), item.owners.map(function (o) { return o.emailAddress }).join(',')]);
      }
    }
    if (token == '') {
      ss.toast('That was the last ' + resp.items.length + '. Your Done!');
    } else {
      ss.toast('Another ' + resp.items.length + '. Keep Going!');
    }
  } while (token)
  sh.getRange(2, 1, vA.length, vA[0].length).setValues(vA);
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
}

function getPathFromId(id) {
  try {
    var file = DriveApp.getFileById(id)
    var pA = [];
    pA.push(file.getName());
    var folder = file.getParents();
    while (folder.hasNext()) {
      var f = folder.next();
      pA.push(f.getName());
      folder = f.getParents()
    }
    var r = pA.reverse().join(' / ');
  }
  catch (e) {
    return e;
  }
  return r;
}
```

You will need to enable drive API.

You can add the downloadUrl to this

```
vA.push([item.id, item.mimeType, item.kind, item.title, getPathFromId(item.id), item.owners.map(function (o) { return o.emailAddress }).join(','),item.downloadUrl]);
```

and to the header here:

```
var vA = [["Id", "MimeType", "Kind", "Title", "Path", "OwnerEmails","Url"]];
```

Comment: This code worked. Thank you Very much!! I had to change my sheet name to Files1 & enable drive API as you mentioned. This code does not return the URL for the file? How it can populate the link for the file & date of start?

Comment: I did try yesterday, it creates a column titled URL, but does not populate any links in that column